# Kotlin compiler does not find import kotlin.test

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to compile the following via command-line:

```
import kotlin.test.assertTrue
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    assertTrue(false)
}
```

However, the compiler fails with:

```
$ kotlinc -d MyCode.jar MyCode.kt 
MyCode.kt:1:15: error: unresolved reference: test
import kotlin.test.assertTrue
              ^
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test` and `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit` specified in dependencies? `kotlin.test` is not a base module